# Understanding The Pure Imaginary Infinity

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let a complex function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and consider

$$\int_{a - i \infty}^{a + i \infty} f(z)dz, ~ a \in \mathbb{R}$$

My question: can we rewrite this like:

$$\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{a - ib}^{a + ib} f(z)dz, ~ a \in \mathbb{R}$$

,or

$$\lim_{b \to i\infty} \int_{a - b}^{a + b} f(z)dz, ~ a \in \mathbb{R}$$

Both are correct? Im trying to understand the concept of the "imaginary" infinity $i \infty$.

Comment: Complex infinity is a point, a family of neighbourhoods is the outer of all cicles  of any radius, in the same way, as the inner  disks have limit point 0. Your first limit is interpreted as a  teh limit along the positive real axis, by real analysis conventions. The second integral limit is not defined in general, because for all $ c:  c*\infty =\infty$, yielding a contour independent limit  for integrals with a fixed value at infinity or a pole, no essential singularity, only.

Comment: The notation $\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}$ means $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{a-ib}^{a+ib}$. I think many would interpret the second notation in that way as well, with $\lim_{b\to i\infty}$ being understood correctly as a limit along the positive imaginary axis, but at the end of the day it's just notation and the notation which is clearest, wins. The first limit is clearer